# upgrade ubuntu server from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS

Tags: server, upgrade, backup

Right now I have ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. This server is important for our production, so I need to update server to 14.04 LTS carefully. I did setup LXC containers and each container have their own process running(e.g gitlab, database,..). What I want to know is should I take any backup before update, if yes how should I take backup. It is first time for me to upgrade server OS and also I'm new to ubuntu. If some thing goes wrong our production will get effect badly.

I want to know how long would it take to upgrade.

Comment: Why I don't get even comments at all?. Is it danger to upgrade to ubuntu server's latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still just released ( ubuntu 14.04 ) and not tested for such purpose as yet . But do not worry you do not need to update the host it self ( 12.04 is supported till 2017 ) only thing is containers them self that is what you needed. Good thing with containers is that they are just a bunch of files , backup them and test them is everyting ok with upgrades.
Cheers.